# How to check if a variable is a file local variable

Tags: compilation, file-local-variables

Some background, I have some code that sets a default compile command depending on the mode.  However, in some files, I've used the `add-file-local-variable-prop-line` to create a more specific command, and this overwrites that.  I need to check if compile-command has been defined for the file, so I don't assign a default value when the file already has a `compile-command`.

I've tried using `file-local-variables-alist`, but it's value is nil, even when there are local variables.

Answer (score 2):

*Where* are you trying to use `file-local-variables-alist`?

[If you're using a mode hook, local variables haven't been processed yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147060/how-can-i-access-directory-local-variables-in-my-major-mode-hooks)

Use `hack-local-variables-hook`.

Comment: I'm not using a mode hook, so I expect it's something else.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, though.

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to use it a function bound to a keyboard shortcut.  It looks like something in my init file was causing some file local variables to not be processed.

Comment: I guess. Check with `C-h v` to see whether the variable has a buffer-local value or not. If not, then you could use recursive bisection on your config until you figure out the cause.